# Determine Whether A Preference Relation Satisfies The Continuity Axiom - from Exercise 1.1 in Game Theory: Analysis of Conflict by Roger Myerson

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics, game-theory, preferences, decision-theory

I am self-studying game theory using Game Theory: Analysis of Conflict by Roger Myerson. Here is an exercise from the textbook. I tried it myself, but I am not sure if it is correct. I would really appreciate it if someone could help me check!

### **Question**

> Suppose that the set of prizes $X$ is a finite subset of $\mathbb{R}$, the set of real numbers, and a prize $x$ denotes an award of $x$ dollars. A decision-maker says that, if he knew that the true state of the world was in some set $T$, then he would weakly prefer a lottery $f$ over another lottery $g$ (that is, $f \succsim_T g$) if and only if
> \begin{align*}
> \min_{s \in T} \sum_{x \in X} xf(x|s) \geq \min_{s \in T} \sum_{x \in X} xg(x|s).
> \end{align*}
> (That is, he prefers the lottery that gives the higher expected payoff in the worst possible state.) Does this preference relation satisfies the continuity axiom?

### **Axiom**

> **Continuity Axiom**$\quad$ *If $f \succsim_S g$ and $g \succsim_S h$, then there exists some number $\gamma$ such that $0 \leq \gamma \leq 1$ and $g \sim_S \gamma f + (1 - \gamma)h$.*

### **My Attempt**

I am not completely sure whether this axiom is satisfied by the preference relation or not. I tried a couple of examples, but failed to show any violation. So I tried to prove that this preference relation does satisfy the continuity axiom, and here is my attempt:

> **Proof**$\quad$ Suppose $f \succsim_T g$ and $g \succsim_T h$. Then,
> \begin{align*}
> \min_{s \in T} \sum_{x \in X} xf(x|s) \geq \min_{s \in T} \sum_{x \in X} xg(x|s) \geq \min_{s \in T} \sum_{x \in X} xh(x|s).\tag1
> \end{align*}
> Let $s_1$ be any state of the world such that
> \begin{align*}
> \min_{s \in T} \sum_{x \in X} xg(x|s) \geq \sum_{x \in X} xh(x|s_1).\tag2
> \end{align*}
> Let $\gamma \in [0,1]$. By definition, we have
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{x \in X}x(\gamma f + (1 - \gamma)h)(x|s) = \gamma \sum_{x \in X} xf(x|s) + (1 - \gamma) \sum_{x \in X} xh(x|s). 
> \end{align*}
> We defined a procedure of finding a $\gamma \in [0,1]$ such that $g \sim_T \gamma f + (1 - \gamma)h$, that is
> \begin{align*}
> \min_{s \in T} \sum_{x\ in X} x g(x|s) = \min_{s \in T} \left\{\gamma\sum_{x \in X}xf(x|s) + (1 - \gamma)\sum_{x \in X}xh(x|s)\right\}.
> \end{align*}
> Let $s_1$ be the real state of the world. By (1) and (2), we have
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{x \in X} xf(x|s_1) \geq \min_{s \in T} \sum_{x \in X} xg(x|s) \geq \sum_{x \in X} xh(x|s_1).
> \end{align*}
> Thus, there exists a $\gamma_1 \in [0,1]$ such that
> \begin{align*}
> \min_{s \in T} \sum_{x \in X} xg(x|s) = \gamma_1 \sum_{x \in X} xf(x|s_1) + (1 - \gamma_1)\sum_{x \in X}xh(x|s_1).\tag3
> \end{align*}
> If
> \begin{align*}
> \gamma_1 \sum_{x \in X} xf(x|s_1) + (1 - \gamma_1) \sum_{x \in X} xh(x|s_1) = \min_{s \in T} \sum_{x \in X} x(\gamma_1 f + (1 - \gamma_1)h)(x|s),
> \end{align*}
> then we are done. If not, let $s_2$ denote the state of the world such that
> \begin{align*}
> \gamma_1 \sum_{x \in X} xf(x|s_2) + (1 - \gamma_1) \sum_{x \in X} xh(x|s_2) = \min_{s \in T} \sum_{x \in X} x(\gamma f + (1 - \gamma)h)(x|s).
> \end{align*}
> Since, by (3),
> \begin{align*}
> \gamma_1 \sum_{x \in X} xf(x|s_2) + (1 - \gamma_1) \sum_{x \in X} xh(x|s_2) < \min_{s \in T} \sum_{x \in X} xg(x|s),\tag4
> \end{align*}
> and since, by (1),
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{x \in X} xf(x|s_2) \geq \min_{s \in T} \sum_{x \in X} xg(x|s),
> \end{align*}
> we must have
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{x \in X} xh(x|s_2) < \min_{s \in T} \sum_{x \in X} xg(x|s).
> \end{align*}
> Then, there must exists a $\gamma_2 \in [0,1]$ such that
> \begin{align*}
> \gamma_2 \sum_{x \in X} xf(x|s_2) + (1 - \gamma_2) \sum_{x \in X} xh(x|s_2) = \min_{s \in T} \sum_{x \in X} xg(x|s).\tag5
> \end{align*}
> Next, I prove that
> \begin{align*}
> \gamma_2 \sum_{x \in X} xf(x|s_1) + (1 - \gamma_2) \sum_{x \in X} xh(x|s_1) \geq \min_{s \in T} \sum_{x \in X} xg(x|s).\tag6
> \end{align*}
> Assume to the contrary that
> \begin{align*}
> \gamma_2 \sum_{x \in X} xf(x|s_1) + (1 - \gamma_2) \sum_{x \in X} xh(x|s_1) < \min_{s \in T} \sum_{x \in X} xg(x|s).
> \end{align*}
> Then
> \begin{align*}
> \gamma_2 < \frac{\min_{s \in T} \sum_{x \in X} xg(x|s) - \sum_{x \in X}xh(x|s_1)}{\sum_{x \in X} xf(x|s_1) - \sum_{x \in X}xh(x|s_1)} = \gamma_1,
> \end{align*}
> where the equality comes from equation (3). But, by (4), we have
> \begin{align*}
> \gamma_1 < \frac{\min_{s \in T} \sum_{x \in X} xg(x|s) - \sum_{x \in X}xh(x|s_2)}{\sum_{x \in X}xf(x|s_2) - \sum_{x \in X}xh(x|s_2)} = \gamma_2,
> \end{align*}
> where the equality comes from equation (5). Therefore, we get a contradiction. So, the inequality (6) holds. Moreover, (6) implies $\gamma_2 \geq \gamma_1$. Again, if
> \begin{align*}
> \gamma_2 \sum_{x \in X} xf(x|s) + (1 - \gamma_2) \sum_{x \in X} xh(x|s) = \min_{s \in T} \sum_{x \in X} x(\gamma_2 f + (1 - \gamma_2)h)(x|s),
> \end{align*}
> then we are done. If not, we repeat the above process. By this procedure, we are always able to find a $\gamma \in [0,1]$ such that $g \sim_T \gamma f + (1 - \gamma)h$. Therefore, this preference relation satisfies the continuity axiom.

### **My Question**

Could someone please help me check if my answer is correct? I really appreciate it!

If the continuity axiom is, in fact, violated, please share a counterexample. If the continuity axiom is indeed satisfied, but my proof has some flaws or there is a better way to prove it, please also consider sharing it as an answer. Thank you very much in advance!

### **Background Information**

For more background information about notations, axioms, and so forth, please refer to [this post](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/56281/about-theorem-1-1-in-game-theory-analysis-of-conflict-by-roger-myerson).

Comment: There might be a much easier proof using the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: @tdm Thank you so much for your comment! I didn't quite get it how the intermediate value theorem would help prove this, because it assumes the function to be continuous. Could you please share your method as an answer? I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let
$$
w_s(\alpha) = \sum_{x \in X} x\,\,(\alpha f(x|s) +(1- \alpha) h(x|s)).
$$
note that this function is continuous in $\alpha$. Next, let
$$
w(\alpha) = \min_{s \in S} w_s(\alpha),
$$
which is also continuous as it is a minimum of continuous functions.

Note that:
$$
w(1) = \min_s \sum_x x f(x|s), \text{ and } w(0) = \min_s \sum_x x h(x|s).
$$
Also, by assumption $f \succeq_S g \succeq_S h$, so
$$
w(1) \ge \min_{s \in S} \sum_{x \in X} x g(x|s) \ge w(0).
$$
By the intermediate value theorem, there is a $\gamma \in [0,1]$ such that:
$$
\sum_x x g(x|s) = w(\gamma) \equiv \min_{s \in S} \sum_{x \in X} x \,\,(\gamma f(x|s) + (1-\gamma) h(x|s)).
$$
as such, $g \sim_S \gamma f + (1-\gamma) h$